# Find the geometric place of the points from where as we draw the tangents at ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, they are perpendicular.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Determine the geometric place of the points in plane from where as we draw the tangents at the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, the tangents are perpendicular.

I was suggested to let the projections of the foci of the ellipse be on a circle $C(O,a)$. Then, let $M$ be a point with this given property: the tangents that intersect through him are perpendicular. We construct a circle of diameter $MF'$( whose middle point we shall denote by $M'$) which intersects the other circle in $I$ and $J$, and the tangents through $M$ to the ellipse will pass through $I$ and $J$. Because $\angle IMJ$ is of $90$ degrees, $IJ$ is a diameter in the second circle, so $JMIF'$ is a rectangle whose diagonals intersect in $M'$. Thus, $|OM|^{2}+|OF'|^{2}=|OI|^{2}+|OJ|^{2}$ from where I would get $|OM|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and thus $M$ would be on $C(O,\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$.

I have one problem with this solution: no matter how I tried, the points $I$ and $J$ where not on the tangents. And I tried with Geogebra, a lot. I have a guess that this solution has therefore a flaw. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a geometric approach, but I'll proceed with algebra just in case you only have to find the locus itself.

The tangent line with slope $m$, to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is given as :

$$y = mx \pm \sqrt{a^{2} m^{2} + b^{2}}$$

and the tangent line perpendicular to it, with slope $- \frac{1}{m}$ is given as :

$$y = - \frac{1}{m} x \pm \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{m^2} + b^{2}}.$$

Now change each equation to make :

$$y - mx = \pm \sqrt{a^{2} m^{2} + b^{2}}$$

and

$$my + x = \pm \sqrt{a^{2} + m^{2} b^{2}}.$$

Now square each equation and add them :

$$(m^{2}+1) (x^{2}+y^{2}) = (m^{2}+1)(a^{2}+b^{2})$$

Therefore we get a circle where

$$x^{2}+y^{2} = a^{2}+b^{2}.$$

This is called a [director circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle) of an ellipse.